# Upwards referencing in verilog without name?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66532989/input-a-reference-to-another-module-in-a-module-instantiation-systemverilog/66533443) verilog supports "upwards name referencing". My question is if it's possible to use something else than the module name to do this hierarchical reference:

1. Can the instance name of the parent be used (`d1`, `d2`)?
2. Is there some builtin `$parent` or similar?

Example where module name `DUT` is used to do upwards referencing:

```
module DUT(input clk);     
   wire a;
   function void hello;
      $display("Hello from %m");
   endfunction

   printer p(clk);
endmodule
    
module printer(input clk);
   always @(posedge clk)
      $display("a is %d", DUT.a);  // Can this "DUT" here be replaced with something else?
   initial DUT.hello;
endmodule

module TB;
   reg clock;
   DUT d1(clock);
   DUT d2(clock);      
endmodule
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use an instance name. In that case it will go all the way up to the TB scope and find `d1` and `d2`. All the search rules are explained in section *23.8 Upwards name referencing* in the [IEEE 1800-2017 SystemVerilog LRM](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8299595).

Basically the rules are look in the local scope first for the first part of that *scope_name*. Then look in the enclosing scopes within the current module, then look up the instance tree. Once it finds the *scope_name* (`d1` in your case), then `d1.a` must exist. It will not continue searching for another `d1` scope. (BTW, these rules remain unchanged from Verilog)

There is no `$parent` for an anonymous upwards reference. There is `$root` in SystemVerilog for an absolute reference.

Comment: Does this in effect mean that the printer instantiations can't reference `a` in the example in the question?

Comment: @moberg No, just use `DUT.a` to reference the `a` one level above.